# Merging nested classes and keeping values

Tags: javascript, class, object, nested

I would like to extend one object in a class `alpha.helper` to be an instance of the `Helper` class, with the added difficulty of setting this everytime a `alpha.helper` function is called because I need to transfer the current value of `alpha.imperfect`.

```
var _ = require("underscore");

var Helper = function(imperfect){

    var helper = {};

    helper.use = function(item){
        console.log(item);
        console.log(imperfect);
        return false;
    }

    helper.bar = function(item){
        console.log(item);
        console.log(imperfect);
        return false;
    }

    return helper;

}

var Alpha = function(){

    var alpha = {};

    alpha.imperfect = {}    

    alpha.add = function(item){
        _.extend(alpha.imperfect, item);
    }

    alpha.helper = function(){
        var helper = new Helper(alpha.imperfect);
        return helper;
    };

    return alpha;

}

var alpha = new Alpha();

alpha.add({"name":"thomas"});

alpha.add({"something":"seven"});

alpha.helper.use("foo");
```

Comment: There is no reason to use the `new` keyword when your functions just return objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
alpha.helper = new Helper(alpha.imperfect);
```

> with the added difficulty of setting this everytime a alpha.helper function is called because I need to transfer the current value of alpha.imperfect.

No. The `helper` always has access to the current `imperfect` value, because it still references the same object.

Comment: When I call `new Alpha()` it runs `alpha.helper = new Helper(alpha.imperfect)` with the current value of `alpha.imperfect` which is `{}`. So this doesn't work. =[

Comment: Why not? If that object becomes populated, the helper will see the populated object. Have you actually tried your code?

Comment: This is working, I'm having trouble with another function that is breaking it. Sorry for the false alarm! THAANKSSS